# running a program from a service

Tags: c++, windows-services, path, environment-variables

I am working on a windows service written in C++ using vs2005 and I'm running into a problem.

The service must launch an other small executable and get it's output. I do that through a call to CreateProcess (well a library does that for me actually (libexecstream) ), it works.

The executable being launched, is somewhere on the disk, I don't know where, and it's directory is in the path environment variable. My service just launch "theTool.exe" and here we go.
If the path variable looks like this: `smting;smthingelse;C:\Program Files\blah\bin;meow` it works.
But if the path looks like this: `smting;smthingelse;%ProgramFiles%\blah\bin;meow` it no longer works!

The problem is, on some machines it looks like the first, on others like the second...
The funny thing is that if I launch it in a console (as opposed to as a service) it works fine!

Is there a way to avoid that problem? programatically? 
A solution like changing it by hands is not an option (the client doesn't want it). Changing it in the install script or something like that is not an option either because the path might be changed afterwards.
And modifying the tool is not an option either because we didn't do it and we don't have the source code.

**edit:**
the CreateProcess line looks like this:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof( si ) );
si.cb=sizeof( si );
si.hStdError = err.w();
si.hStdOutput = out.w();
si.hStdInput = in.r();
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof( pi ) );
if( !CreateProcess( 0, const_cast< char * >( command.c_str() ), 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi ) ) {
throw os_error_t( "exec_stream_t::start: CreateProcess failed.\n command line was: "+command );
}
```

where `command` is "theTool"

**2nd edit**: if my program is launched as a service it fails, if it is launched in a console it workds

Comment: Are you running this on 64bit or 32bit platforms?  Are all supported platforms the same architecture?

Answer (score 3):

Environment variable problems can be tricky, especially when you are talking about services.  A few thoughts:

1. Use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to verify which user the process is running as.  Make sure that the user under which the service is running has the appropriate environment vars setup (although this shouldn't be an issue with one as vanilla as %programfiles%)
2. If you are somehow programatically changing the environment variable, there are know problems with caching the [environment vars on startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887693).

Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

`%ProgramFiles%` is another environment variable within your environment variable value entry. You need to resolve it. If when parsing out the path you encounter this pattern you should then look it up and use the UNC path of all parts to point to your file.

Couple ways to skin the cat here:

- Use `GetEnvironmentStrings` windows API to get everything up front and put them in a map for easy lookup by your service
- Use `GetEnviromentVariable` to check the existence and get the value of a specific environment variable for example `ProgramFiles`
- Query the registry for the environment variables at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`
- Set your own environment variable rather than using `PATH` which should be reserved for system stuff and not fooled around with anyway
- Use a more robust filesystem library which has functionality for dealing with environment variables
- Forget environment variables and use a configuration file (this could be accompanied by a simple GUI program that allows them to use a open file dialog to browse and select paths which will be stored for your service to pick up and use later)
- Etc

Comment: so you're suggesting to scan the path manually? (I'm referring to your first 3 solutions) it sounds like a lot of work for something that should work out of the box :/ as for the 4th and 6th, as I said to Adam, we don't control what the tool does.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly your service must use an app which can't be changed and doesn't work? That's a conundrum.

Comment: it does work! the service just fails to call it when run as a service. From a console it works fine

Comment: Ah wait a minute that's a different problem. Are you using a relative path when calling `CreateProcess`? If so you should know that a windows service is executed from the system directory not from the folder the executable image resides in. You can probably just copy this tool program into `System32` if you want a low impact hack to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `CreateProcess`, you could instead [use the `App Paths` registry key](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/25/10189298.aspx) and launch the application with [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This avoids polluting the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The 'tool' is not from us, we don't have the source code, nor do we have a choice to use it or not. So the path solution is more or less forced on us. I'll look if it is registered in the App Path registry key but I doubt it.